# Can I use the Podman container engine instead of the Moby Engine on Azure IoT Edge devices?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

After analysing i see some advantages of using podman container engine instead of moby engine, like Rootless Containers,No Daemon,Better Integration with Systemd,Enhanced Security Features. So I wanted to know that is it possible to use podman in IoT edge devices?

I wanted to know whether it is feasible before trying this.

Comment: I doubt that it would work, but, if it did, it would be unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

as Mark pointed out, Microsoft recommends using moby-engine on production instances as it the only container engine officially supported with Azure IoT Edge. Please refer the documentation [Azure IoT Edge supported platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/support?view=iotedge-1.4#container-engines) for more details.

You may still use Podman in dev or sandbox environments. However, you would have to handle configuration and testing of these modules yourself.